# Sulu CMS "403 Forbidden" for Admin page

Tags: homestead, sulu

I am running homestad 6.1.0 and followed the guide on http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/book/getting-started.html to start a sulu project.

I added `app.php` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/sulu.test` because the start page returned 403 Forbidden. The start page is available now but i still cant access the admin page.

Permissions for web folder are set correctly

I have no idea what I can do now and hope you have a hint or solution for me.

I don't have [Homestead Improved](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-get-homestead-vagrant-vm-running/) running yet

Comment: The getting started guide uses the built-in webserver to get started even faster, but there is another page for permissions (http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/cookbook/web-server/nginx.html), have you executed these commands there? It's not only about the web folder.

Comment: Yes, I have executed this commands but with errors: "Operation not supported" and "No such file or directory" . I have seen your comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829144/sulu-cms-installation-errors-with-laravel-homestead so I will try to get it running with Homestead Improved

Comment: Let us know in case it is not working with this answer either.